# How to wrap a fig close to a description/itemize list?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure

I want to make a description list with a figure in the right side.
I prefer wrapping the fig, but It´s good in any other kind of wrapping

I code this, but I have no good results, It´s strange, place the fig after the description list

```
\item Los tres tipos de anomalías son:\\
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{40mm}  %\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{36mm}

    \includegraphics[width=40mm]{anomalias.jpg}
  \end{wrapfigure}  %\end{wrapfigure}


     \begin{description}
        \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
        \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
        \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
        \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
        \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
       \end{description}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to let a `wrapfigure` wrap around a list, as stated in the very beginning of the `wrapfig` documentation:

> You must not specify a `wrapfigure` in any type of list environment or
>   or immediately before or immediately after one. It is OK to follow a
>   list if there is a blank line (`\par`) in between.

I don't have your complete code, but you can adapt this solution to your document.

You can split the `description` environment in two parts: the first one will go inside a `minipage` and the second one will follow a second `minipage` containing the image.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove the demo option in your document

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\linewidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  \begin{description}
    \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
    \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
  \end{description}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
  \vspace*{4pt}
  \raggedleft
  \includegraphics[width=40mm]{anomalias.jpg}
\end{minipage}

\begin{description}
  \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
  \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
  \item [- Verdadera.-] Es el ángulo que forma el planeta medido desde el foco de la órbita con el eje de la elipse. Se designa por $\nu$, por $T$, o por $V$
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I had tried any similar, but I obtained no good results. If I copy yout code, works well, but if I adapt it,  you can see, with a copy of your propose https://www.dropbox.com/s/yktafpzjs4qu4ly/Resumen%20de%20cosas%20para%20examen%20de%20astronomia.tex

Comment: @MikaIke Your code is wrong... There must not be any blank line between `minipage`s and also the first `\end{minipage}` must end with `%`.

Comment: @MikaIke Also, if the image has `width=14mm`, it looks better if the first `minipage` has `0.85\linewidth` and the second `0.15\linewidth`

Comment: Ok, @karlkoeller Perfect answer!! For this kind of things, ... do you recommend me "minipage"?, or do you recommend me other packages as/like wrapfig or floatflt ?

LATEX is so beautifull!! is so complicated :-)

Comment: @MikaIke `wrapfig` is OK for normal text, but not when you have special environments like lists.